# Proto message requiring a 'ref'-parameter when trying to instantiate

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I have the following proto-message:

```
message MyClass
{
    optional int64          _abc                = 1 [default = 0];
    optional double         _def                = 2 [default = 0];
    optional int64          _ghi                = 3 [default = 0];
    optional int64          _jkl                = 4 [default = 0];
    optional string         _mno                = 5 [default = ""];
    repeated SomeType       _someTypes          = 6;
}
```

For some reason, protobuf-net generates the following constructor for this class (taken from the **metafile**):

```
public MyClass(int aAbc, double aDef, int aGhi, int aJkl, ref string aMno);
```

Why does it require a 'ref' type for the last parameter? I've created several very similar messages and it didn't happen with them. I can't really provide more code, because there actually isn't any more to it.

Edit: I edited out the C# part since I've removed the partial C# class form my code aswell.

Comment: Firstly, I'd strongly suggest using automatically implemented properties - the size of your class will shrink massively :) Secondly, I wonder whether the `ref` is due to the default you've got in the proto? Try removing it...

Comment: Hey thanks, I'll remove my properties.
Deleting the default didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Can I check: do you really mean protobuf-net? or do you mean protobuf-csharp-port? I don't remember protobuf-net creating non-trivial constructors...

Comment: yeah, I've double-checked, and protobuf-net generates `public SubEvent() {}`. Retagging.

Comment: I don't think this is protobuf-csharp-port either - we never generate public constructors for messages at all :) (We generate them for builders, but they're parameterless.)

Comment: Sorry, Marc. I didn't clarify this enough. The constructor header is taken from the metafile. The constructor within my pb.cs is `public MyClass() {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this turned out to not be directly related to protobuf-net, instead it was a problem with a class of the same name in a C++ wrapper. The compiler preferred this over the protobuf-generated class.